# How to find in which hook(s) a certain function is called?

Tags: hooks, eldoc

I'm using the `lsp` layer on Spacemacs with `javascript-backend 'lsp` and it activates two modes I don't like: `lsp-ui-mode` and `eldoc`.

I found `lsp-ui-mode` inside `lsp-mode-hook` and added `(remove-hook 'lsp-mode-hook 'lsp-ui-mode)` to my `init.el`, which fixed that.

But I can't find where `eldoc-mode` is being called. How do I search for it within (all?) hooks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `debug-on-entry` <kbd>RET</kbd> `eldoc-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>

(and <kbd>M-x</kbd> `cancel-debug-on-entry` <kbd>RET</kbd> to undo that.)

This will show you what called `eldoc-mode`, each time it is invoked.

To learn about the debugger, see <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Debugger` and especially `(elisp)Debugger Commands` (so you know how to use it).

---

In this case, the cause is almost certainly `global-eldoc-mode` which is a globalized minor mode.  Globalized modes act in `after-change-major-mode-hook`, which happens after the major mode hook has run (and so you can't use the major mode hook to disable the associated buffer-local `eldoc-mode`).

If you don't want `eldoc` at all, just add `(global-eldoc-mode -1)` to your init file.

Comment: Thank you, `debug-on-entry` did it. I added `(global-eldoc-mode -1)` to my init file but it wasn't enough. Then through the debugger I found out I had to also set `lsp-enable-eldoc nil`. Also found `lsp-ui-doc-enable` and `lsp-ui-sideline-enable` and turned them off to stop annoying overlays on hover.

Answer (score 1):

You can use command `apropos-value` to find all variables whose values match some pattern: `M-x apropos-value eldoc-mode`. Then search the results buffer for just the variables whose names end in `-hook`.

Comment: Thank you! This does exactly what I asked for, but it was less helpful as there were too many results and I couldn't sift through them to find the culprit. Using `debug-on-entry` I also found out that `eldoc-mode` wasn't getting called in a hook at all, but rather in a piece of code that checked for the `lsp-enable-eldoc` condition and then called `eldoc-mode` directly.